# ArrayList of ArrayList of Integers

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Integers. [ArrayList > list]. How do I set value foe an index of any inner ArrayList? I do not want to build an ArrayList of Integers and add them to the List of List using add function, but I want to set values to it, as I already have the List of List.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) It will help people help you if you show how you're creating the lists with code, and say quite precisely what you want to do after creating them.

Comment: `myListOfList.get(index1).set(index2, myInteger);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you have something like:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(outerSize);
```

You've also said:

> I do not want to build an ArrayList of Integers and add them to the List of List using add function, but I want to set values to it, as I already have the List of List.

If that's true, it means you've already done this or similar:

```
for (int i = 0; i < outerSize; ++i) {
    List<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<>(innerSize);
    for (int j = 0; i < innerSize; ++i) {
        inner.add(defaultValue);
    }
    list.add(inner);
}
```

So given all of that, it's just `get` (to get the inner list from the outer list) and `set` (to set a value on it):

```
list.get(outerIndex).set(innerIndex, value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped.

Comment: Also, if I have just initialised an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Integer, there are no elements yet, how do I add an element to it?

Comment: @PradiptaSarma - `get` the inner list you want to add to, then `add` to it: `list.get(outerIndex).add(value);`.